# Javascript array showing 0 length when populated

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm sure this is really simple but I haven't had much luck figuring out what's wrong.   I'm creating an empty array (locations), filling it with location objects in the `getPartnerLocations` function and then trying to plot the locations on the map with the `drop` function.   The problem I'm  having is that inside the `drop` function the locations array which has stuff in it is returning a length of zero so the loop in the isn't working.  Any tips or ideas about what's going on here would be greatly appreciated.

```
var markers = [];
var locations = [];
var iterator = 0;
var map;
var geocoder;
var newYork = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7143528, -74.0059731);


  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: newYork
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);

  }

  function getPartnerLocations() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();    
      $('.partner').each(function(index){

            var street  = $('.partner-streetaddress',this).text();
            var city    = $('.partner-city',this).text();
            var state   = $('.partner-state',this).text();
            var country = $('.partner-country',this).text();

            var address = street + ', ' + city  + ', ' + state + ', ' + country;

            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) 
            {

                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                {
                    locations.push( results[0].geometry.location ); 
                    console.log(locations[index]);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('failed to geocode address: ' + address);   
                }
            });

      });
      initialize();
      drop();
  }

  function addMarker() {
    console.log('add marker function');
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: locations[iterator],
      map: map,
      draggable: false,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));
    iterator++;
  }

  function drop() 
  {
    console.log(locations.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        addMarker();
      }, i * 200);
    }
  }

 getPartnerLocations();
```

Comment: is it possible to post a stripped down demo on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geocode` is an asynchronous function.

The callback doesn't execute until some time *after* you call `drop`.
Therefore, when you call `drop`, the array is still empty.

You need to call `initialize` and `drop` after the last AJAX call replies, in the `geocode` callback.